# elasticsearch warning : this request accesses system indices but in a future major version, direct access to system indices will be prevented

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana

when I send a POST request, I received warning

`org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient: request [POST http://localhost:9200/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512]`

`returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.14.2-6bc13727ce758c0e943c3c21653b3da82f627f75 "this request accesses system indices: [.apm-agent-configuration, .apm-custom-link, .kibana_7.13.4_001, .kibana_task_manager_7.13.4_001, .tasks], but in a future major version, direct access to system indices will be prevented by default"]`

Now, I understand that system indices will be hidden in the future and cannot be accessed. What is the correct usage or command to send so that this warning will not be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

your use of `POST http://localhost:9200/_search` is querying *all* indices in Elasticsearch, which you probably don't really want to be doing

you're better off specifying which indices you want to query